# you just wrote a binary to decimal converter

Tags: c

I cant get this to work. I get this... That is 6295636 in decimal
the program is simply converting a binary of four bits to a decimal interpretation. I think my logic is sound but I cant tell

```
#include <stdio.h>

int result = 0;

int power2 = 8;

char num;

int main(){

    printf("Enter FOUR 1's and/or 0's followed by a '*'.\n");
    scanf("%c", &num);

    while (num != '*'){
        if (num == ' '){
            printf("\n");
        } 
        else if (num == 1){
            result = result + power2;
        }
        power2 = power2 / 2;

        scanf("%c", &num);
    }
    printf("That is %i in decimal", &result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("That is %i in decimal", &result);` should be: `printf("That is %i in decimal", result);`. You want to print an `int`, not the address of the variable

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have two errors:

```
else if (num == 1)
```

You are using `%c` in `scanf`, so you are reading the value as a character. So
you have to check `num == '1'`, because `1 != '1'`. See the [ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.com/) for more information about the numeric values of characters.

The second error is

```
printf("That is %i in decimal", &result);
```

Here you have to pass `result`, but you are passing `&result` which is a pointer
to `int`. `&result` is the address of the variable `result`. Also add a newline
to the `printf`:

```
printf("That is %i in decimal\n", result);
```

Also there is no reason for declaring `result`, `power` and `num` as global
variables, why are you doing that? Just declare them inside the `main`
function.

It is also a good idea to check the return value of `scanf` to see whether it
succeed in reading and converting the value from the user, this makes the
program more robust. You should also check if the user entered something
different from `'1'` and `'0'`.

So the corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int result = 0;
    int power2 = 8;
    char num;

    printf("Enter FOUR 1's and/or 0's followed by a '*'.\n");
    int ret = scanf("%c", &num);

    if(ret != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not read from user\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (num != '*') {
        if (num == ' '){
            printf("\n");
        } else if(num == '1' || num == '0') {
            // num - '0'  would give you either 1 or 0
            result = result + (num - '0') * power2;
            power2 = power2 / 2;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input '%c', ignoring\n", num);
        }

        ret = scanf("%c", &num);
        if(ret != 1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not read from user\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    printf("That is %i in decimal\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you soo much...I cant wait for my understanding to be better so that I may contribute as you have ~one love